# Deleting HealthKit sample failing on watchOS 2

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, healthkit

I’d like add samples to HealthKit from an iPhone app and Apple Watch app. There is one condition: If another sample has already been added in the last 10 minutes I want to replace it (or delete + add).

Here’s what I do.

```
func addOrUpdateSample(beans:Float) {

    let dateThreshold = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-10 * 60)
    let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"startDate >= %@",dateThreshold)
    let sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: true)

    let query:HKSampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: caffeineType!, predicate: predicate, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors:[sortDescriptor]) { (query, results, error) in

        // Remove all samples that match the predicate…

        if results != nil {
            for result in results! {
                self.healthStore?.deleteObject(result, withCompletion: { (success, error) in })
            }
        }

        // …before adding the new sample

        let sample = self.createSample(beans) // Helper returning a HKQuantitySample object
        self.healthStore?.saveObject(sample, withCompletion: { (success, error) in })
    }

    healthStore?.executeQuery(query)
}
```

On iOS this works as expected, deleting all existing objects before adding a new one. When initiated from the Apple Watch App however a sample is being added but no sample gets deleted?

Is deleting samples not supported on watchOS or did I miss something?

Comment: Where do you see that it isn't deleted? on the watch or on iPhone? There are some bugs in that area prior to iOS 9.3. Similar cases that I know appear to be fixed in 9.3 in my tests.

Comment: Have you check the error parameter of the completion? By the way, a more efficient way to delete samples matching a predicate is to call 
deleteObjectsOfType().

Comment: @Allan Yes, thanks, that's a much better method for what I am doing.

Comment: @GerdCastan I found that the deleteObjectsOfType() when excuted from watchOS only deletes HealthKit samples that were created on watchOS but not the ones created on iOS. Hmmm

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564761/healthkit-workout-saved-on-iphone-not-visible-in-activity-app for my test results. Feel free to report bugs to Apple for some additional motivation.

Comment: @GerdCastan Thanks. Looks like this is very much in the same field of issues although I am not dealing with HKWorkouts but HKSamples directly. Also interestingly I found that when adding/deleting samples on the iPhone, the HealthApp reflects this directly when I switch to it. However when *deleting* samples on watchOS it only shows up in the Health App after force quitting and re-launching it. But *adding* items from watchOS also shows up directly. Not sure if this is helpful. I am confused. Another idea. Could it have something to do with threading…?

Comment: My issues are about HKWorkouts *and* HKSamples (although different sample types and my samples are tied to workouts).