# HealthKit : Issue with associated samples deletion of provided workout

Tags: swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

Using HealthKit, I am saving below data:

1. Workout
2. Active Energy
3. Distance

I am deleting workout using below code:

```
self.healthStore?.delete(workout, withCompletion: { (status, error) in
```

But above code just deletes a workout from HealthKit app. I want to delete workout and it's associated samples. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete associated samples we need to perform delete query on specific `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier`.

To delete Active Energy from Workout refer below code:

```
 let energyBurnedQuantity = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: workout)

    let energyQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: energyBurnedQuantity!, predicate: predicate, limit: 100, sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, result, error) in

        if error == nil {
            guard let resultData = result else {
                return
            }

            if resultData.count > 0 {
                self.healthStore?.delete(resultData, withCompletion: { [unowned self] (status, error) in

                    if status == true {

                        print("Successfully deleted Energy.")
                        })
                    } else {
                        print("Error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    self.healthStore?.execute(energyQuery)
```