# On iOS, without an Apple Watch, how to collect totalEnergyBurned for a workout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

When saving a workout to the iOS health store, without any Apple Watch, how should an app calculate totalEnergyBurned?

Apple's example app uses a hard coded value for totalEnergyBurned, but says a real-world app would calculate this values from sensor data.

```
HKQuantity *energyBurned = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit] doubleValue:425.0];

HKQuantity *distance = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit mileUnit] doubleValue:3.2];

HKWorkout *run = [HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeRunning
                                          startDate:start
                                            endDate:end
                                           duration:0
                                  totalEnergyBurned:energyBurned
                                      totalDistance:distance
                                           metadata:nil];

[self.healthStore saveObject:run withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Thank you

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564761/healthkit-workout-saved-on-iphone-not-visible-in-activity-app?rq=1

Comment: when you say "The Apple" I assume you mean "The Apple sample code"?

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't give you a way to do this out of the box unless you have an Apple Watch.

Apps like Strava and Nike Run calculate calories burned based on factors like:

- gender
- body weight
- distance of run
- duration of run

You can look for formulas on google, or even elsewhere here on the Stack Exchange network: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15608/energy-expenditure-calories-burned-equation-for-running which in turn links to good resources around the web